# How to list all files belonged to different branches in Mercurial?

Tags: linux, mercurial, branch, tortoisehg, redhat

I am new to the mercurial so sorry for the newbie  question.
I have created a local repository called "localRepo" at /home/Cassie/localRepo. I have two branches there, default and src1-branch. For default branch, it has file1,file3 and for src1-branch, it has file1, file2 and file4. Whenever I tried to list all files at that repository, it only shows the files belong to the current branch.

For example, if current branch is src1-branch, then if I typed

```
ls -l
```

It showed only

```
file1 file2 file4
```

Is there any way to see all files belong to the same repository such as

```
file1 file2 file3 file4
```

I have tried

```
hg status --all
```

It still only showed file1 file2 and file4.

My machine is redhat linux workstation 6 with mercurial 1.7 and tortoisehg.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2):

`hg manifest --all` lists all files in all revisions, including deleted and renamed files.

Given:

```
o  5: Removed file1, Renamed file3->file6
|
| @  4: Added file5
| |
| o  3: Added file4
| |
o |  2: Added file3
| |
o |  1: Added file2
|/
o  0: Added file1
```

Result of `hg manifest --all`:

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.However, maybe because it is due to the version of my mercurial, I could not execute the command `hg meanifest --all`. No such command exists in my system. Any other idea ? Thanks,

Comment: Upgrade? :^)  It looks like `--all` was added in 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

There are no standard ways that I know of but you can use the approach mentioned by you.

```
hg branches ------ tells you all the branch
branch1
branch2
.....

hg update -C branch1    ----- switches you to a branch1
hg status --all         ----- provides all files for branch1

hg update -C branch2    ----- switches you to branch2
hg status --all         ----- provides all the files for branch2
```

You can merge the output of all the branch and remove redundant file names.
You can write a script to do that.

**Also `-C` is dangerous** as it discards files while changing to a branch. Hence should be used only if you no changes lying in working directory that you want to commit.

**Caveat**: This idea is usually not good way to see files in two different branches.

You can add a file c.txt when you are in branch1 and again add another c.txt in branch2 with different contents.

In this case, semantically it is two different files with the same name.